# SQL Server query - keeping first and last unique records of a group

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

We are trying to remove and rank data in tables that is provided in a daily feed to our system.  the example data of course isn't the actual product, but clearly represents the concept.

Daily inserts:

1. data is imported daily into tables that continually updates the status of the products
2. the daily status updates tell us when products were listed, are they currently listed and then the last date it was listed
3. after a period of {X} time, we can normalize the data

Cleanup & ranking:

1. we are now trying to remove duplicate records for values in a group that fall in-between the first and last values
2. we also want to set identifiers for the records that represent the first and last occurrence of those unique values in that group

Sample data:

[image]
I've found that the photo is the easiest way to show the data, show what's needed and not needed - I hope this makes it easier and not obtuse.

In the sample data:

- "ridgerapp" we want to keep the records for 03/12/17 & 06/12/17.
- "ridgerapp" we want to delete the records that fall between the dates above.
- "ridgerapp" we want to also set/update the records for 03/12/17 & 06/12/17 as the first and last occurrence - something like -
- update table set 03/12/17 = 0 (first), 06/12/17 = 1 (last)
- "sierra" is just another expanded data sample, and we want to keep the records for 12/06/16 and 12/11/16.
- "sierra" delete the records that fall between 12/06/16 and 12/11/16.
- "sierra" update the status/rank for the 12/06/16 and 12/11/16 records as the first and last occurrence.
- update table set 12/06/16 = 0 (first), 12/11/16 = 1 (last).

Conclusion:

Using pseudo code, this is the overall objective:

- select distinct records in table (using id,name,color,value as unique identifiers)
- for the records in each group look at the history and find the top and bottom dates
- delete records between top and bottom dates for each group
- update the history with a status/rank (field name is rank) of 0 and 1 for values in each group
- using the sample data, the results would end up

Updated table values:

```
 23  ridgerapp  blue    25  03/12/17    0
 23  ridgerapp  blue    25  06/12/17    1
 57  sierra     red     15  12/06/16    0
 57  sierra     red     15  12/11/16    1
```

Comment: Good job on explaining your first question and using sample data and expected output. For future posts, try and give your sample data as a DDL and DML as i did in my answer below and the results in text instead of images :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice and help, clearly new on here.  Mea culpa.  Advice much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a `CTE` with the `row_number()` window function to find the first and last rows for each *group*, and then update it.

You didn't specify what makes a *group* a *group* so I only based this off the `ID`. If you want the group be a set of columns, i.e `ID` and `Color` and `Value` then just add these columns to the `partition by` list. For the sample data the result would be the same, but different sample data would have different outcomes.

Notice I didn't include the exact rows for the sierra group because I wanted to show you how it'd handle duplicate `history` dates.

```
declare @table table (id int, [name] varchar(64), color varchar(16), [value] int, history date)
insert into @table
values
(23,'ridgerapp','blue',25,'20170312'),
(23,'ridgerapp','blue',25,'20170325'),
(23,'ridgerapp','blue',25,'20170410'),
(23,'ridgerapp','blue',25,'20170610'),
(23,'ridgerapp','blue',25,'20170612'),

(57,'sierra','red',15,'20161206'),
(57,'sierra','red',15,'20161208'),
(57,'sierra','red',15,'20161210'),
(57,'sierra','red',15,'20161210')   --notice this is a duplicate row

;with cte as(
select 
    *
    ,fst = row_number() over (partition by id order by history asc)
    ,lst = row_number() over (partition by id order by history desc)
from @table
)

delete from cte
where fst !=1 and lst !=1

select 
    *
    ,flag = case when row_number() over (partition by id order by history asc) = 1 then 0 else 1 end
from @table
```

**RETURNS**

```
+----+-----------+-------+-------+------------+------+
| id |   name    | color | value |  history   | flag |
+----+-----------+-------+-------+------------+------+
| 23 | ridgerapp | blue  |    25 | 2017-03-12 |    0 |
| 23 | ridgerapp | blue  |    25 | 2017-06-12 |    1 |
| 57 | sierra    | red   |    15 | 2016-12-06 |    0 |
| 57 | sierra    | red   |    15 | 2016-12-10 |    1 |
+----+-----------+-------+-------+------------+------+
```

Comment: awww, thank you so much!  the attention to detail in your answer and question I asked goes above and beyond.  this is exactly {exactly!} what i was looking to do and my lowely vote for the answer being correct didn't move the needle.  but this is 100% correct.  many thanks again - j

Comment: No problem @seligtech you can select the check mark for correct answers. Best wishes.